# How to query for an exact ManyToMany relation?

Tags: django, many-to-many

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class Votable(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Vote(models.Model):
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Votable, related_name='+')
    choosen = models.ForeignKey(Votable)
```

Notes:

`Vote.options` have exactly 2 items

`Vote.choosen` is one of the 2 items of options

How do I make a query that search for the exact 2 items of `Vote.options` and also `Vote.choosen`?

I tried `Vote.objects.get(options=[1,2], choosen=1)` but it returns:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to chain filters to get only vote objects that have both options 1 and 2.

```
Vote.objects.filter(options=1).filter(options=2).get(choosen=1)
```

---

If you wanted vote objects that had either `options` 1 OR 2 you'd use `__in` syntax:

```
Vote.objects.get(options__in=[1, 2], choosen=1)
```